How can I enable swipe typing and autocorrect in Juice SSH?
The Juice SSH app disables swipe typing and autocorrect on the keyboard by default. How can I switch these features back on?
The Juice SSH FAQ says to swipe right on the keyboard1:

In normal JuiceSSH operation autocomplete, autocorrect and swipe typing are disabled. If you want to enter text with these features enabled, you can do so by swiping right on our popup keyboard. When done, just swipe it back to switch back into command input mode.

Elsewhere, they say to swipe left2:

Because it interferes with typing in commands. But swipe left on the popup keyboard it will go into autocomplete/autocorrect mode.

However, neither swiping right nor left does anything with the keyboard, neither within Juice SSH nor within any other app.

After much trying, I finally found out how this works:

You have to swipe left. Swiping right doesn't work. (I. e., their FAQ is wrong, their other post is correct.)

You have to swipe on the additional keyboard space Juice SSH provides (with the ESC TAB CRTL ALT etc. keys). Swiping on the "standard" Android keyboard doesn't do anything special.


There is an option in the Juice SSH preferences which places that additional keyboard space at the top of the screen (so that the terminal window is between the standard keyboard and the additional keyboard space). This makes it easier to swipe correctly.
